# Finding identical values in multiple columns in R

Tags: r

### How to check if values in a data frame occur in many columns.

- I have a table of many rule codes tested in different year periods.
- The idea is to find how many rule codes are repeated each year and return a list.
- The hard part is that there are thousands of rules and they are not arranged in a column, and of course not all of them are necessarily repeated, but about 90% or more are repeated every year.
- As an example, one rule is at the top of the first column and at the bottom of the third column, so checking if rows are identical is not suitable.
- **I have tried the following method**: I have separated the columns into tables and checked column value duplicates in other tables with the method **a[a %in% b]**, but this takes too long and does not give an accurate result in the long run.
- Maybe apply or lapply would be the solution?

  structure(list(`Rules Year 1` = c("R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.C.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.B.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.2.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.3.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.4.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.2.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.2.E.F" ), `Rules Year 2` = c("R.KMB.BOSF.1C.C.3.5.3.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.C.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.B.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.1.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.1.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.2.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.3.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.4.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.2.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.2.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.3.2.OV.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.3.E.F"), `Rules Year 3` = c("R.KMB.BOSF.1C.C.3.5.3.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.C.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.3.2.OV.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.3.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.4.2.OV.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.B.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.1.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.2.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.3.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.4.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.2.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.1.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.2.E.F"), `Rules Year 4` = c("R.KMB.BOSF.1C.C.3.5.3.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.C.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.B.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.1.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.2.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.3.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.4.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.2.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.1.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.2.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.E.F",  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.3.2.OV.E.F", "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.3.E.F" )), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ))

The expected output would be a list of rule codes that occured in each column. The ones that are in one, two or three columns should be eliminated from the output:

```
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.C.E.F"            "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.E.F"             
 [3] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.B.E.F"              "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.E.F"       
 [5] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.E.F"   "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.3.E.F"  
 [7] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.E.F"          "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.2.E.F"         
 [9] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.4.E.F"   "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.E.F"           
[11] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.1.E.F"          "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.2.E.F"
[13] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.2.E.F"          "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.1.E.F"
[15] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.3.E.F"            "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.E.F"           
[17] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.1.E.F"   "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.1.E.F"
```

Comment: `table(dat)` will return the number of times each rule appears in your entire dataset `dat`. What is your expected result?

Comment: If you want to know which rules appear in *every* year, you can use `Reduce(intersect, df)`.  Othewise, you should make a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post the expected output.

Comment: Images are not a good way of posting data (or code). Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(rules_df, 20))`. Also include the expected output corresponding to the posted data set.

Comment: `table(dat)` is not suitable, because seperately in a column every value is unique, but accros all columns the same value is repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `table(dat[,n])` on each column to get a count list of each unique item in the column. Then you can compare the data for each column.

Or you can do `table(dat)` as suggested in the comment to get a count list of each unique item in your data frame.

Update based on comment:

1. Because it's a huge data set, I'd convert it to a data.table.

```
setDT(df)
```

2. Extract a list of all unique rules in the entire data set.

```
rules_list = unique(unlist(df))
```

3. Find out which columns contain each of these rules using `apply()` to find matching rules in each column with `grepl()`

```
for(rule in rules_list) {
print(rule)
print(apply(df, 2, function(x) any(grepl(rule, x))))
}
```

4. Or, as you mentioned, if you're looking for only rules that are present in all years

```
for(rule in rules_list) {
if( sum(apply(df, 2, function(x) any(grepl(rule, x)))) == ncol(df) ) {
print(rule)
}}
```

Given: `df` is the table you gave as an example.

```
rules_list
 [1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.E.F"                  "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.C.E.F"            "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.E.F"             
 [4] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.B.E.F"              "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.E.F"                "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.1.E.F"             
 [7] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.E.F"              "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.E.F"            "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.E.F"         
[10] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.E.F"        "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.1.E.F"   "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.E.F"  
[13] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.1.E.F" "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.2.E.F" "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.3.E.F"  
[16] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.4.E.F"   "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.2.E.F"          "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.E.F"           
[19] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.1.E.F"          "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.2.E.F"          "R.KMB.BOSF.1C.C.3.5.3.E.F"             
[22] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.3.2.OV.E.F"       "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.3.E.F"            "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.4.2.OV.E.F" 

for(rule in rules_list) {
print(rule)
print(apply(df, 2, function(x) any(grepl(rule, x))))
}

[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.C.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.B.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.1.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.1.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.1.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.2.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.3.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.4.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.2.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE        FALSE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.1.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.2.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
        TRUE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.1C.C.3.5.3.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
       FALSE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.3.2.OV.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
       FALSE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.3.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
       FALSE         TRUE         TRUE         TRUE 
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.4.2.OV.E.F"
Rules Year 1 Rules Year 2 Rules Year 3 Rules Year 4 
       FALSE        FALSE         TRUE        FALSE

for(rule in rules_list) {
if( sum(apply(df, 2, function(x) any(grepl(rule, x)))) == ncol(df) ) {
print(rule)
}}

[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.C.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.A.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.A.B.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.1.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.1.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.1.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.2.2.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.3.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.1.2.RS.4.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.1.2.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.1.E.F"
[1] "R.KMB.BOSF.V1.C.1.B.2.2.2.E.F"
```

Of course, instead of `print()`, you can save them in a list or anything you want.

I think this is what you were expecting!

Comment: `table(dat)` won't work with many rows, it's inconvenient and is not showing the wanted result.

Comment: Ah! I think I understood what you want. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Additionally, can you please add how to save it as a list, not character? It has to be done in the first {} or the second {}. Thank you!

Comment: This error is showing when using the second for loop. `Error in if (sum(apply(df, 2, unction(x) any(grepl(rule, x)))) == ncol(df)) { :   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`